# Laravel unique email validation is not working on different character case in mongodb

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a registration form with unique email validation. When I enter different character case, emails does not apply unique validation.

`example@gmail.com, Example@gmail.com, eXample@gmail.com`: Laravel unique validation is failed.

`example@gmail.com, example@gmail.com, example@gmail.com`: Laravel unique validation is success.

Please check my code below and correct me. Email is storing as lowercase in database.

DB - Mongodb,

Framework - Laravel 5.5

[jenssegers/laravel-mongodb is using to connect laravel and mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
  return Validator::make($data, [
     'firstName' => 'required|string|max:255',
     'lastName' => 'required|string|max:255',
     'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:user,usrEmail',
     'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
  ]);
}
```

**User.php** (Model)

```
public function setusrEmailAttribute($value)
{
  $this->attributes['usrEmail'] = strtolower($value);
}
```

Comment: Try use only `'email' => 'required|email|unique:user,usrEmail',`

Comment: @Pyton, Not working

Comment: Try also convert `$data['email']` to lowercase. Maybe this is a problem with case sensitive.

Comment: Do you have a `users` table or a `user` table?

Comment: @Pyton I have already applied laravel feature mutators  so, when user register email will store as lowercase.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I am using user table

Comment: check last post. 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9430

Comment: @MustafaToker I tried but it's not working. I resolved this issue with laravel custom validation rule

Comment: Take your validations in a request file (( oop alert))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of laravel custom validation rule I resolved this issue.

I create a new rule using php artisan command `php artisan make:rule Lowercase` and defined the rule.

**app/Rules/Lowercase.php**

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
 return strtolower($value) === $value;
}

public function message()
{
    return 'The :attribute must be lowercase.';
}
```

I have attached the rule object with other rules

**RegisterController.php**

```
use App\Rules\Lowercase;
protected function validator(array $data)
{
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'lastName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => [ 'required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:user,usrEmail', new Lowercase ],
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'dataProtection' => 'required',
            'termsService' => 'required',
        ]);
}
```

While registration users enter email, system will alert the users to use lowercase.

It works for me I am not sure this a good approach or not.

Comment: I don't see the point in requireing the user to set his email lowercase.. however, we might do this automatically in the client js.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. By doing it this way, it enforces it before the user gets their account into the system. So the user will know what to expect. 

Answer (score 3):

You may use `strtolower($data['email'])` before validation.

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $data['email'] = strtolower($data['email']);
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstName' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'lastName' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:user,usrEmail',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you already closed this out but I did want to propose two possible alternative solutions.

**[Form Request Validation: After Hooks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation)**

For this approach you would create a custom form request (like you did) and do something like this:

```
/**
 * Configure the validator instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 */
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
        }
    });
}
```

In here you would be able to cast the email to lowercase and compare it with your database. This way you don't have to rely on the user reentering the email. You only have to go back to the user with an error if the email is not unique. In short, this allows you to perform extra validation.

**[Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware)?**

The second way, and probably not the right way, would be using a custom Middleware. I don't see a reason why you couldn't setup something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckEmail
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->someIsUniqueChecker($request->email)) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($someErrors);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The advantage of using Middleware would be that you will know if the email entered is unique before it hits your validation. Some things to consider!

Answer (score 0):

I have the simplest solution to fix unique email issue in MySql in Laravel

Just make your field unique by using below query:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD UNIQUE(`email`);
```

This solved my case-sensitive and unique issue, did not need to make any changes in any controller and model scripts. Thanks to ask this question.